# Do we control this new "Chat with an expert" feature?

Tags: feature-request

There appears to be a new feature today for "Chat with an Expert." I tried it out. It reminds me of that old Elisa AI demo. It's a bot. I'm not sure that it is useful. Do we get any choice to whether we run this feature on SharePoint.Stackexchange.com? We might consider turning it off unless we can point to the benefit of the feature.

Comment: Nope, you don't get a choice :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert

Comment: It is an April Fools joke so I imagine it'll be turned off soon

Comment: It was pretty funny. It suggested I use MongoDB instead of SQL Server; consequently failed the Turing test :-)

Comment: It was pretty impressive too, it kept asking me to create a SharePoint group when I asked for if she's real or not Lol. For a moment I thought it was real but expert's picture didn't helped

Comment: Nice. I fell for it. Got me!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just have to.

[image]